# Sprockets find_asset doesn't translate files within rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsx, sprockets, rake-task

I have a rails application using react-rails with jsx assets, and I would like to see the pure js translation of these files within a rake task.

Within the rails console, I can achieve this with the line `Rails.application.assets.find_asset(jsx_file_path).to_s`

However, when I put this line in a rake task, it returns the untranslated contents of the jsx file (console and the rake task were executed in the same rails environment).  Why does sprockets behave differently in the rails console and a rake task, and how can I configure it to behave the same in the rake task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: I needed my rake task to depend on `:environment` so that the rails application gets initialized before the task is run.

After changing `task :my_task do` to
`task :my_task => :environment do` everything works the same in the rake task as it does in the console.